# How to run the .exe or .bat files(with arguments) present in a shared/remote location using sql server jobs

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, exe, sql-job

I need to run  a .exe and .bat files which are present in a different server locations using sql jobs.

After doing an extensive search i could come up with below options

1. Inside sql job step setting "Operating system(CmdExec)" as type and the executable path as below,

c:\path.exe (or) \some\shared\path.exe  ----->this seems to work

but unable to run the same with parameters like below

"c:\path.exe" "servername" "database"  --->not working

(or)

"\some\shared\path.exe" "servername" "database"  --->not working

2. DECLARE @command varchar(8000)
   SET @command = 'C:\MyProgram' 
   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

even this not working, moreover people say this is not  secured to enable cmdshell inside servers, so i am left with above option only.

3. Also the same can also be done using power shell which i haven't tried

any suggestions or help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name = 'your_job', @step_id = 1,
        @step_name = 'OS Exec', @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC',
        @command = 'dir c:\'
;
```

Or in SSMS in the step_1 definition use this syntax:

```
echo servername database
```